# How to prevent excessive function calls in JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an element which autosaves its contents via an AJAX call. Currently, whenever the contents change the autosave function is called. However, I'd like to limit this a bit to reduce the number of server requests. What would be the best way of editing the following code so `save()` is called no more than once every n seconds?

```
$("#editorInstance").contentChange(function() {
    save();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind another library, underscore has a [`throttle` method](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) which can handle this:

> **throttle** `_.throttle(function, wait)`
>
> Creates and returns a new, throttled version of the passed function, that, when invoked repeatedly, will only actually call the original function at most once per every **wait** milliseconds. Useful for rate-limiting events that occur faster than you can keep up with.
>
> ```
> var throttled = _.throttle(updatePosition, 100);
> $(window).scroll(throttled);
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can delay the execution  of the function, using setTimeOut()

```
var init;
$("#editorInstance").contentChange(function() {
    init = setTimeOut(save, 60000); //After a minutes
});

//Do you forget to clear the timeout too
function save() {
     clearTimeOut(init);
     //Remaining function
}
```

Or, you might want to disable the editor, when it is being saved.

```
$("#editorInstance").contentChange(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    save();
    $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: perhaps you should add a `clearTimeout()` before you add a new `setTimeout()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout#Example

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would solve it,

```
$("#editorInstance").contentChange(function() {
    if(!window.saveTimeout)
        window.saveTimeout = setTimeOut(save(), 60000);
    else
        clearTimeout(window.saveTimeout);
        window.saveTimeout = setTimeOut(save(), 60000);
});
```