# Prevent a function from being fired too rapidly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function. It is being triggered from many other functions in the script. Sometimes very rapid and maybe almost simultaneously

How can I prevent it from being triggered too rapidly within short time? By setting a delay or timer of some sort? I want to minimize the database calls the function is making

But there should be no delay in the function if it's not needed.. Meaning: First call = no delay. All other calls = only delay if previous call was less than x seconds ago. 
And if the delay is set to let's say 5 seconds, the function should only wait 1 second if the previous call was made 4 seconds ago.. Hope you understand what I mean ;)

```
function checkusers() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/checkusers_in_db.php',
        type: 'POST'
    });

};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent excessive function calls in JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861823/how-to-prevent-excessive-function-calls-in-jquery)

Comment: You can use counter somwthing like var myCall = 0; then myCall++; inside function loop and then proceed as required

Comment: Will the call return different results each time?  I.e. can you 'cache' the result on the client for X amount of seconds?

Comment: You can (i) add your AJAX calls to a queue (ii) de-queue and process requests using setInterval

Answer (score 0):

Underscore.js has method `debounce`, that could be helpful here

> debounce_.debounce(function, wait, [immediate]) 
>   Creates and returns a new debounced version of the passed function that will postpone its execution until after wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time it was invoked. Useful for implementing behavior that should only happen after the input has stopped arriving. For example: rendering a preview of a Markdown comment, recalculating a layout after the window has stopped being resized, and so on.

http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Use like this:

```
checkusers_with_delay = _.debounce(checkusers, how_much_delay);
```

and then use the `checkusers_with_delay` in all those multitudes of other functions

Comment: this of course requires you to include underscore.js in you webpage, but it's a great library anyway

Comment: On a closer look, the `throttle`-function that is documented above debounce fits the bill even better

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the COMET pattern (long polling)

Refactor checkusers so it looks at your users cache rather than call via AJAX. As a separate piece of code have an AJAX call into the PHP page, which upon return refreshes your user cache.

The secret is that the PHP could "hold" the HTTP request until it has some/enough data to send back to your page. Then upon receipt of the response, your page makes another AJAX request, rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I built my own resize function that:

- Prevent a function from being fired too rapidly by using [this](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/) by Paul Irish
- Can be bound on all selectors (not just $(window)) by using [this](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) bu Ben Alman

simply import this code:

```
/*
 * jQuery resize event - v1.1 - 3/14/2010
 * http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010 "Cowboy" Ben Alman
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * http://benalman.com/about/license/
 */
(function($,sr){

    // debouncing function from John Hann
    // http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/
    var debounce = function (func, threshold, execAsap) {
        var timeout;

        return function debounced () {
            var obj = this, args = arguments;
            function delayed () {
                if (!execAsap)
                    func.apply(obj, args);
                timeout = null;
            };

            if (timeout)
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            else if (execAsap)
                func.apply(obj, args);

            timeout = setTimeout(delayed, threshold || 500);
        };
    }
    // resize
    jQuery.fn[sr] = function(fn){  return fn ? this.bind('resize', debounce(fn)) : this.trigger(sr); };

})(jQuery,'resize');
```

and then import the Ben Alman resize() event.

Answer (score -1):

This will trigger the ajax if it hasn't run in the last 30 seconds.

```
var last_checkuser_time = new Date();  

function checkusers() {

    var now = new Date();
    var timeout = now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() - 30);
    if (last_checkuser_time < timeout) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/checkusers_in_db.php',
            type: 'POST'
        });
        last_checkuser_time = new Date();
    }

};
```

Comment: Will this queue calls to the function or simply not run if last call was less than 30 seconds ago?

Comment: But this will also delay the first call?